# How can I make django url alias?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-admin, django-2.0

I am using django rest framework filters in my app. For a viewset that looks like following:

```
class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    lookup_field = 'slug'

    filter_backends = (SearchFilter, DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = ('category__slug','brand__slug')
```

It adds following url:

```
http://*.compute.amazonaws.com:8000/product/?category__slug=smart-phone&brand__slug=asus&
```

I want to keep using `DjangoFilterBackend` as I am using, but I want the api to look like following:

```
http://*.compute.amazonaws.com:8000/categories/smart-phone/brands/asus
```

I know that I can use RedirectViews but I don't want to redirect user. Can I somehow make alias urls without using nginx or other reverse proxy tools?